# Qweb: How can i compute value of an array using index?

Tags: python, qweb

I want to access and compute array in `qweb` using index, I initialise the array with :

```
<t t-set="total" t-value="[0]*len(data['quantity'])/>
```

The code looks like :

```
<t t-foreach="lines" t-as="line">
     <t t-set="i" t-value="0"/>
     <t t-foreach="data[line]['quantity']" t-as="qty">
          <t t-set="total[i]" t-value="total[i]+data[line]['quantity'][qty]"/>
          <t t-set="i" t-value="i+1"/>
     </t>
</t>
```

but the line with t t-set="total[i]" t-value="total[i]+data[line]['quantity'][qty]" seems to doesn't work
Can you help me? Thank you.
I want something like that :

[image]

Comment: It would be useful if you can provide the full error trace.

Comment: Now it works (no error) but the total[i] is still 0

Comment: Then why did you mention that _"it gives you error"_ ?

Comment: it gave me errors and i modified the code. Now, it works but the t t-set="total[i]" t-value="total[i]+data[line]['quantity'][qty]"/> doesn't compute the total

Comment: Why are you putting all this logic in your template?  This sort of computation is usually done in your man Python code, and then you pass the pre-computed structures to your templating engine.  I bet you'd have an easier time if you could do this.  Templating engines are not designed to do this sort of stuff.  It's harder to know what's going on under the hood.

Comment: I see a problem in your logic.  Because you increment 'i' every time in your loop, you are not accumulating a total in each total[i].  Your line `<t t-set="total[i]" t-value="total[i]+data[line]['quantity'][qty]"/>` is logically equivalent to `<t t-set="total[i]" t-value="data[line]['quantity'][qty]"/>` because `total[i]` will always be 0 when this line is computed.

Comment: Do you maybe want to move each of the lines that sets 'i' up one level? ie: `<t t-set="i" t-value="0"/>` before the first **for** and `<t t-set="i" t-value="i+1"/>` before the second **for**

Comment: @Steve I thought that I can do that computation when the result I mean the total is just only for view on hardcopy document (no need that in the base)

Comment: [SOLVED] I did it in serveur side. Thanks

Comment: Glad you solved your problem.  I kinda get what you're saying.  But as you saw, it's better to do the stuff in the Python.  Do remember though...unless I'm missing something.  This is all happening on the server either way, right?  What comes over the wire is the rendered version of the template, not the template itself. - I can see where it might be nice to only have to to change the template, but that an idea usually done to modify aesthetics, not calculate new core data.